# How to sort an array ascending and descending?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

```js
let setOfNumbers =[5,2,8,1,9];

const orderedNumbers = arr => {
    if(arr instanceof Array === false) return console.warn('El dato ingresado no es correcto');
    
    if(arr.length === 0) return console.warn('El array debe contener al menos un numero');
    
    for(let num of arr){
        if(typeof num !== 'number') return console.warn('El array debe contener solo numeros');
    }
   
    let descendingNum = arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return b - a;}); 
        console.log(descendingNum);
    
    let ascendingNum = arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;});  
        console.log(ascendingNum);
    
    
    let objOrderedNum = {
        descendingNum, 
        ascendingNum 
    }
    return console.log(objOrderedNum);

}

orderedNumbers(setOfNumbers);
```

Hi, I need to do a function in JavaScript that returns an object with two arrays that contains the numbers of the array input by user, sorted in descending and ascending order. In the first `console.log()` works ok, but in the final object it isn't working.

Comment: because sort changes the original array. You need to make a copy.

Comment: Use `let x = [...arr].sort(...)` to make a copy

Comment: also `return console.log(objOrderedNum)` will return `undefined`

Comment: thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `sort` sorts in-place. You will need to make a copy like `[...arr]`

Answer (score 0):

sort mutates the array so when you sort it once and again, it will change. So you have to make a copy.

```js
var a = [1,4,6,8,3];
a.sort();
var b = a.slice().reverse(); // [...a].reverse();
console.log({ a, b });
```

Comment: thanks for  your help, this answer solved the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of your original array. As per your code, updated working code.

```
let setOfNumbers =[5,2,8,1,9];

const orderedNumbers = arr => {
    let arr1 = [...arr];
    if(arr instanceof Array === false) return console.warn('El dato ingresado no es correcto');
    
    if(arr.length === 0) return console.warn('El array debe contener al menos un numero');
    
    for(let num of arr){
        if(typeof num !== 'number') return console.warn('El array debe contener solo numeros');
    }
   
    let descendingNum = arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return b - a;}); 
        console.log(descendingNum);
    
    let ascendingNum = arr1.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;});  
        console.log(ascendingNum);
    
    
    let objOrderedNum = {
        descendingNum, 
        ascendingNum 
    }
    return console.log(objOrderedNum);

}

orderedNumbers(setOfNumbers);
```

Comment: `let arr1 = arr;` <-- still same array

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks for your feedback.